# How to get Azure service fabric performance metrics?

Tags: azure, azure-service-fabric, azure-application-insights, azure-log-analytics, azure-monitoring

On Azure service fabric cluster, how to get the performance metrics we need from App Insights to tell us what specifically limits the load the SF cluster can handle? metric like CPU on the nodes, Memory on the nodes

Answer (score 0):

App Insights cover different business needs & don't focus on providing metrics for CPU, RAM, Drive IOPS, etc.

If you need a simple solution right from the box, you should take a look at [VM insights](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/blog/rich-insights-for-virtual-machines-from-azure-monitor/), it can scrape metrics from scale sets. But it's not very convenient overall if you're required to have alerting and get more detailed information.

Second, and the best option is to use 3rd party services for monitoring, for instance, **Datadog**, **Dynatrace**, etc. But they all will cost you a lot if you have, more or less, complex infrastructure.

I can advise you to look at **Prometheus** and get more from it.